# How to update temp table data during run time AX 2012

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

I'm new to X++ development. I'm trying to add a field in Vendor aging report. It was done as excepted.

my problem is updating the field value during run time.

**Scenario**,
We have a Invoice field contain "AA_BBBBBB". What I need to do is I need to split the value as AA, BBBBBB and update BBBBBB to invoice field and AA to new field (Invoice type).

**Issue**,
Once i got the values to temptable VendAgingReportTmp in the method VendAgingReportDP\insertVendAgingReportTmp, I'm tried to update the above scenario but `code is not selecting the records from VendAgingReportTmp`. Can someone help me to get this thing done.

Comment: Can you post the code you're working that's not working?

Comment: Also take a look at how to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a solution by adding below,

- Added **InvoiceType** field to temptable **VendTmpAccountSum** Since this is declared as global variable.
- Updated our custom Invoice type to **InvoiceType** field in **VendTmpAccountSum**.
- Then insert the whole data to **VendAgingReportTmp** from **VendTmpAccountSum** table by using **insert_recordset** to increase the performance.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

In `VendAgingReportDP` class `insertVendAgingReportTmp` the last line of standard code is `vendAgingReportTmp.insert();`

If your code is before `vendAgingReportTmp.insert();` You do not need to perform the update. If you put `vendAgingReportTmp.update();` before `vendAgingReportTmp.insert();` you get that error.

Put your code inside `//YourCode` and `//YourCode END` withhout `vendAgingReportTmp.update();`

***Example:***

```
/// <summary>
///    Inserts records into the temporary <c>VendAgingReportTmp</c> table.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="_reverseAmountsAndHeadings">
///    A boolean value which indicates whether the column values should be     reversed.
/// </param>
private void insertVendAgingReportTmp(boolean _reverseAmountsAndHeadings)
{
    vendAgingReportTmp.AsOfDate = strFmt("@SYS84682",     date2StrUsr(contract.parmZeroDate(), DateFlags::FormatAll),     contract.parmDateTransactionDuedate());
    vendAgingReportTmp.HeadingAccount = strFmt("@SYS24500");
    vendAgingReportTmp.HeadingName = strFmt("@SYS7399");

    switch (contract.parmDateTransactionDuedate())
    {
        case DateTransactionDuedate::DocumentDate : vendAgingReportTmp.HeadingDate = "@SYS2587";
                                                break;
        case DateTransactionDuedate::TransactionDate : vendAgingReportTmp.HeadingDate = "@SYS67";
                                                break;
        case DateTransactionDuedate::DueDate : vendAgingReportTmp.HeadingDate =     "@SYS14588";
                                                    break;
        default : vendAgingReportTmp.HeadingDate = "@SYS14588";
                                                    break;
    }

    if (_reverseAmountsAndHeadings)
    {
        this.setVendAgingReportTmpInReverse();
    }
    else
    {
        this.setVendAgingReportTmp();
    }

    vendAgingReportTmp.TransDate = tmpAccountSum.TransDate;
    vendAgingReportTmp.InvoiceId = tmpAccountSum.InvoiceId;
    vendAgingReportTmp.Voucher = tmpAccountSum.Voucher;
    vendAgingReportTmp.AccountNum = tmpAccountSum.AccountNum;
    vendAgingReportTmp.Name = vendTable.name();
    vendAgingReportTmp.VendAccount = tmpAccountSum.AccountNum;
    vendAgingReportTmp.Txt = tmpAccountSum.Txt;
    vendAgingReportTmp.Balance = 100;
    vendAgingReportTmp.CurrencyCode = tmpAccountSum.CurrencyCode;
    vendAgingReportTmp.VendGroup = vendTable.VendGroup;

    //YourCode
    //...
    //...
    //...
    //YourCode END

    vendAgingReportTmp.insert();
}
```

Comment: Actually We are using insert_recordset

Comment: @SankarR: Please [edit] this information into your question to increase your chances for an answer.

Comment: @SankarR Add your code please, to give you a correct answer.

Comment: finally I got the solution Jon and update here. Thanks for all your help :)